# why does this attributed string stmt crash?

Tags: nsattributedstring

I'm trying to learn how to use attributed strings. This statement caused a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS":

```
NSDictionary *attDict = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor] };
```

The way I read the documentation NSForegroundColorAttributeName is an NSString, so I then tried this but got the same crash:

```
NSLog(@"NSForegroundColorAttributeName: %@", NSForegroundColorAttributeName );
```

and also this and got the same crash:

```
NSString *fcan = NSForegroundColorAttributeName;
```

So it looks like any mention of NSForegroundColorAttributeName causes a crash. I did try other xxxAttributeNames and they do the same thing. I am importing UIKit/UIkit.h. There are no compiler warnings and no run time messages. What am I missing? Is there something else I need to import or assign?  Do I have the whole concept wrong? I don't think there are any Apple code samples that cover this.

Comment: I added: #import <CoreText/CoreText.h>  but still the same crash.

Answer (score 0):

Using the newer NS* constants compiles because the extern for them is present in a header (if you build with "Latest iOS" SDK, but if you execute this code on a device that has not iOS 6 but lower then you get the crash you describe.